# How can I decrease the space between inputs with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [css form styles from Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#forms) but I would like to decrease the default spacing between the form input fields.  Not sure which css element I need to overwrite.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use Firebug or Webkit's inspector. Also, CSS and structure are changing significantly in the soon-to-come bootstrap 2.0.

Comment: Try to decrease the `margin-bottom` of `form .clearfix`

Comment: Simone Vittori: Thanks, that was it  form .clearfix {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  zoom: 1;
}

Comment: @ceejayoz any idea when 2.0 is due for release?

Comment: No word, but it should be soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with the default setup you can decrease the `.line` margin to achieve your goal. Try this:

```
form .line {
    margin-bottom: 5px; //adjust to your liking
}
```

This is of course if you're working with an input field separated by the line div that the bootstrap uses, e.g.:

```
<div class="line">
        <label for="input">Full Name</label>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" name="input" size="30">
        </div>
</div>
<div class="line">
        <label for="input">Last Name</label>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" name="input" size="30">
        </div>
</div>
...
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/qxMVd/1/

Answer (score 8):

When using Bootstrap v2.1 I use their horizontal forms to reduce the height of my forms,  I then find altering the .control-group bottom margin can give the desired effect.

Default is 20px I beleive,  I use 8px

```
.form-horizontal .control-group {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```